# What is swinging at the issue mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

[image]I want to know the meaning of the phrase **"swinging at the issue"** in this sentence:

- When bad things happen we typically compounded the problem by swinging at the issue.

Comment: I have never heard this expression before. Can you provide a link to the place where you found it?

Comment: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tVONvTPid3c/V2Fxx6uwmlI/AAAAAAAAA98/6IAFPc8DdZs_eYps_-VilwKqzF_hGFOtQCKgB/s1600/Inspirational-happy-weekend-67g.jpg is the link,please check

Comment: The page at that link doesn't include the sentence you mention.  Can you check again?

Comment: sorry for the wrong link, i have edited the question please check and help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to know with context, but this idiom originally comes from baseball. In baseball, when you are batting, the ball comes, and you have a chance to swing at it. If you hit it, you can run. If you miss, you get a strike. This has gradually come into common vernacular.

> When bad things happen we typically compounded the problem by aggressively swinging at the issue.

So, it appears bad things happened to us. Reading between the lines, instead of getting a group effort together, one person (or at least a smaller group) at a time tried to fix the problem (they swung at it). That usually didn't work, and just made the problem worse.

Swinging almost implies a half-hearted, patchy, or time-pressed attempt, instead of a full effort.

EDIT:

The image in OP is trying to teach a lesson. When bad things happen, instead of "aggressively swinging," or spending all of your time trying to fix the problem(s), the image suggests slowing down, and waiting for good timing, or help from someone more knowledgeable, or just waiting for it to fix itself, instead of trying to fix something you might know nothing about.

> In life, there are no failures, only lessons.

This summarizes the whole image - learn from your mistakes, don't just try to get rid of them, and failure tells you how to not do it next time.

Comment: sorry for the wrong link, i have edited the question please check and help me out.

Comment: @B.shruti edited - let me know if it is still unclear